# group a column by date with different formats

Tags: r, date, group-by

I have a dataset where one column has a date and time  values. Every date has multiple entries. The first row for every date has a date value inthe form `29MAY2018_00:00:00.000000` while the rest of the row for the same date has time values i.e. `20:00 - 21:00`. The problem is that I want to sum the values in another column for each day.

The sample data has the following format

```
Date                       A
29MAY2018_00:00:00.000000   
20:00 - 21:00              0.009
21:00 - 22:00              0.003
22:00 - 23:00              0.0003
23:00 - 00:00              0
30MAY2018_00:00:00.000000   
00:00 - 01:00              -0.0016
01:00 - 02:00              -0.0012
02:00 - 03:00              -0.0002
03:00 - 04:00              -0.0023
04:00 - 05:00              0
05:00 - 06:00              -0.0005
20:00 - 21:00              -0.0042
21:00 - 22:00              -0.0035
22:00 - 23:00              -0.0026
23:00 - 00:00              -0.001
```

I have created a new column

```
data$C[data$A ==0 ] <- 0
data$C[data$A < 0 ] <- -1
data$C[data$A > 0 ] <- 1
```

I need to sum the column `C' for every date. 
The output should be

```
A                    B
29-MAY-2019          4
30-MAY-2019         -9
31-MAY-2019          3
```

Comment: You don't need 3 assignments.  Just use `data$C <- sign(data$A)`

Comment: 31-MAY-2019 is not showed in the example

Comment: Sorry, but the above data is just a sample, I have many years data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to create a grouping column based on the occurrence of full datetime format in the 'Date', `summarise` the first 'Date', convert it to `Date` format (with `anydate` from `anytime`) and get the `sum` of `sign` of 'A'

```
library(tidyverse)
library(anytime)
data %>%
    group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(Date, "[A-Z]"))) %>% 
    summarise(Date = anydate(first(Date)),
               B = sum(sign(A), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, it worked. I got the result on the terminal but don't know how to get it in a DF

Comment: @Abrar just assign it to a dataframe ```DF <- data %>%
    group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(Date, "[A-Z]"))) %>% 
    summarise(Date = anydate(first(Date)),
               B = sum(sign(A), na.rm = TRUE))```